# API for spokeo? Scraping Spokeo

Tags: python, xml, json, api, web-scraping

Is there any API for spokeo ? I wanted to get results in json or xml format and I tried finding an api for it but couldn't. Has anyone tried scraping spokeo with or without the api ? I'm sure we can scrape in a general way but I dont know how to proceed when search results come up with more than one location area. Thanks

Comment: What is the actual question? As you yourself found, Spokeo doesn't seem to offer a public API. They also don't seem to focus on making their site easily scrapable. If you want to scrape it, you have to analyse their output carefully and come up with a parser that is able to handle the cases you want to handle. Since Spokeo doesn't provide a data model description and a description of how their data model maps to their web site, nobody outside Spokeo can provide you with a spec. You have to do some hard work and write the scraper yourself, and then update it when Spokeo updates their site.

Comment: Yeah thats what I figured, I'm now working on the customized scrapper. Its almost done. just a few changes left. I'll link this post with the git link once I get it working. These days they have added the celebrity news thing. It kinda makes the work messier

Comment: Great! Make sure you answer your own question and accept the answer instead of making another comment, so that it's clear what the solution was and so that the question isn't left without an answer forever. :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4049778

Answer (score 6):

According to Spokeo's [terms of use](http://www.spokeo.com/terms-of-use), scrapers are explicitly prohibited, as are *any* "derivative works" - even if all such works do is frame content from their site.

If you publish this in a publicly available application, be prepared for some flak for it.

Answer (score 3):

I think an easier answer would be to work with the [FullContact Person API](http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/person/)